# Create an array of images then press button to remove one of the images in the array

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, image

I am creating a drawing app in Swift. I which every time a user draws a line on the `UIImageVIew` it rasterizes a new image. I would like to create an undo button which goes to the previous image in the array.

Here is my code -

```
func drawLineFrom(fromPoint: CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint) {

    // 1
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)

    tempImageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height))
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    // 2

    context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: fromPoint.x, y: fromPoint.y))
    context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: toPoint.x, y: toPoint.y))

    // 3

    context?.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.normal)
    context?.setLineCap(CGLineCap.round)
    context?.setLineWidth(brushWidth)
    context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor(red:red, green:green, blue:blue, alpha: 1.0).cgColor)

    // 4
    context?.strokePath()

    // 5
    tempImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    tempImageView.alpha = opacity
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    swiped = true
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let currentPoint = touch.location(in: view)
        drawLineFrom(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: currentPoint)
        lastPoint = currentPoint

    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if !swiped {
        // draw a single point
        drawLineFrom(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: lastPoint)

    }

    // Merge tempImageView into mainImageView
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mainImageView.frame.size)
    mainImageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height),blendMode: CGBlendMode.normal, alpha: 1.0)
    tempImageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height), blendMode: CGBlendMode.normal, alpha: opacity)
    mainImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    tempImageView.image = nil
    floaty.isHidden = false
    postBtn.isHidden = false
    resetBtn.isHidden = false
    undoBtn.isHidden = false
    dismissBtn.isHidden = false
}
```

Comment: Can't you just store the previous image in a var, and then update this on touchesBegan? Then you can add a button which sets the image view to that previous image.

Comment: @PranavKasetti how would I update this on touchesBegan?